# Ajax pagination with Django and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Im building a simple search engine in my app to get some resuts depending a certain criteria. I want to use ajax and jquery to implement the search using ajax and paginate the results. Ajax works fine doing the search but when i try to paginate over the results it only works the first time i hit prev or next and the second time it seems to break.

```
(function(){

$("form#search").on("submit", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);


    $.ajax({

        type:"GET",
        dataType:"html",
        data:$this.serialize(),
        url:"/properties/search/",
        success:function(resp){

            $(".col-md-9").html($(resp).find(".properties"));

        },
        error: function(){

            $(".col-md-9").html('<h1>Verifique los datos ingresados para realizar una correcta búsqueda</h1>');

        }

    })

})

})();
```

// Pagination

```
(function(){

$("ul.pagination li a").on("click", function(event){

    $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.prop("href"));
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        type:"GET",
        dataType:"html",
        url:$this.prop("href"),
        success:function(resp){

            $(".col-md-9").html($(resp).find(".properties"));

        },
        error: function(){

            $(".col-md-9").html('<h1>Verifique los datos ingresados para realizar una correcta búsqueda</h1>');

        }

    })

})

})();
```

// Template

```
       <div class="text-center">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li><a href="/properties/search">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
                        {% if properties.has_previous %}
                            <li><a href="?{{ path }}&amp;page={{ properties.previous_page_number }}">Anterior</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if properties.has_next %}
                            <li><a href="?{{ path }}&amp;page={{ properties.next_page_number }}">Siguiente</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href="#">Siguiente</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <li><a href="?{{ path }}&amp;page={{ properties.paginator.num_pages }}">&gt;&gt;</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue using $(document).on("click", "ul.pagination li a", function(event){})